# Unable to read contents on an Advanced Format disk when using some USB docking stations

Tags: linux, hard-drive, sata, advanced-format, usb-to-sata

I have Linux Mint 17.3 (based on Ubuntu 14.04) with 4.4.0 kernel.
I own a Western Digital Caviar Green WD10EARX hard drive with 1TB capacity. The label on this drive says it is an "Advanced Format" drive. Please note that no jumper is set, so no "compatibility"/"emulation" jumper is set.

I read about Advanced Format drives and their 4k sector size (instead of the standard 512 byte one), but what I can't explain is the different behaviour I see whenever I connect this drive with different USB enclosures or docking stations.

### Example 1: Sunplus USB 2 docking station

lsusb -v shows:

```
Bus 003 Device 013: ID 1bcf:0c31 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. SPIF30x Serial-ATA bridge
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1bcf Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
  idProduct          0x0c31 SPIF30x Serial-ATA bridge
  bcdDevice            1.32
  iManufacturer           1 Sunplus Innovation Technology 
  iProduct                2 USB to Serial-ATA bridge
  iSerial                 3 <removed>
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 Bulk Only Configuration
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                2mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              5 Bulk Only Interface
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

fdisk -l shows:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 testine, 63 settori/tracce, 121601 cilindri, totale 1953525168 settori
Unità = settori di 1 * 512 = 512 byte
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificativo disco: 0x0001cf00

Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            8040      498023      244992   fd  Autorilevamento raid di Linux
/dev/sdb2          498024      562271       32124   fd  Autorilevamento raid di Linux
/dev/sdb3          562272      809271      123500   fd  Autorilevamento raid di Linux
/dev/sdb4          809272   244187999   121689364   fd  Autorilevamento raid di Linux
```

hdparm -I shows:

```
ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       WDC WD10EARX-00N0YB0                    
        Serial Number:      <removed>
        Firmware Revision:  51.0AB51
        Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
        Supported: 8 7 6 5 
        Likely used: 8
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16383
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
        LBA    user addressable sectors:  268435455
        LBA48  user addressable sectors: 1953525168
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
        Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:      953869 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:     1000204 MBytes (1000 GB)
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
        LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
        Queue depth: 32
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, with device specific minimum
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 0
        DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
             Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
             Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
           *    SMART feature set
                Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    Write cache
           *    Look-ahead
           *    Host Protected Area feature set
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
           *    NOP cmd
           *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
                Power-Up In Standby feature set
           *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
                SET_MAX security extension
           *    48-bit Address feature set
           *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
           *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
           *    SMART error logging
           *    SMART self-test
           *    General Purpose Logging feature set
           *    64-bit World wide name
           *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
           *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
           *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
           *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
           *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
           *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
           *    Host-initiated interface power management
           *    Phy event counters
           *    NCQ priority information
                DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
           *    Software settings preservation
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
           *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
           *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
           *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
                unknown 206[7]
                unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
                unknown 206[13] (vendor specific)
Security: 
        Master password revision code = 65534
                supported
        not     enabled
        not     locked
        not     frozen
        not     expired: security count
                supported: enhanced erase
        186min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 186min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 50014ee2b14805a5
        NAA             : 5
        IEEE OUI        : 0014ee
        Unique ID       : 2b14805a5
Checksum: correct
```

And if I cat `/sys/class/block/sdb/queue/physical_block_size` and `/sys/class/block/sdb/queue/logical_block_size` they both say 512.

So, when connecting the hard disk to this docking station, it seems like it's a normal 512-byte sector drive.

### Example 2: USB 2 enclosure with JMicron USB to SATA & PATA Combo Bridge

When connecting the drive to this enclosure, I see a completely different story.

lsusb -v shows:

```
Bus 003 Device 014: ID 152d:2338 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JM20337 Hi-Speed USB to SATA & PATA Combo Bridge
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x152d JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp.
  idProduct          0x2338 JM20337 Hi-Speed USB to SATA & PATA Combo Bridge
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 JMicron
  iProduct                2 USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge
  iSerial                 5 <removed>
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 USB Mass Storage
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                2mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              6 MSC Bulk-Only Transfer
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

fdisk -l shows:

```
Nota: la dimensione del settore è 4096 (non 512)
(in English: Note: the sector size is 4096 (not 512)

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 testine, 63 settori/tracce, 15200 cilindri, totale 244190646 settori
Unità = settori di 1 * 4096 = 4096 byte
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Identificativo disco: 0x0001cf00

Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            8040      498023     1959936   fd  Autorilevamento raid di Linux
/dev/sdb2          498024      562271      256992   fd  Autorilevamento raid di Linux
/dev/sdb3          562272      809271      988000   fd  Autorilevamento raid di Linux
/dev/sdb4          809272   244187999   973514912   fd  Autorilevamento raid di Linux
```

hdparm produces some sort of corrupted result:

```
ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       �����������@������������
        Serial Number:      ������������
        Firmware Revision:  �����
Standards:
        Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x10fd) 
        Supported: 14 11 10 
        Likely used: 14
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       0       0
        heads           0       0
        sectors/track   510     0
        --
        Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes 
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
        IORDY(may be)(cannot be disabled)
        Queue depth: 32
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Vendor
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 255 Current = 255
        Recommended acoustic management value: 234, current value: 0
        DMA: not supported
        PIO: unknown
             Cycle time: no flow control=65535ns  IORDY flow control=24384ns
           *    reserved 69[0]
           *    reserved 69[1]
           *    reserved 69[2]
           *    reserved 69[4]
           *    reserved 69[7]
           *    DEVICE CONFIGURATION SET/IDENTIFY DMA commands
Security: 
        Master password revision code = 19648
        not     supported
        not     enabled
        not     locked
        not     frozen
        not     expired: security count
        not     supported: enhanced erase
Integrity word not set (found 0x0000, expected 0x9fa5)
```

If I cat `/sys/class/block/sdb/queue/physical_block_size` and `/sys/class/block/sdb/queue/logical_block_size` they both say 4096.

So, it seems like this enclosure uses the disk with 4k sector sizes, so as a "native" 4k Advanced Format drive. If I were to stop here, I would say that the other docking station is just "too old" to properly support 4k drives. However, what surprises me is the following.

### Example 3: JMicron USB 3 docking station

When I connect this drive to a much more recent USB 3 docking station, with UASP support, I get results much more similar to the first docking station.

lsusb -v shows:

```
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 152d:0565 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x152d JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp.
  idProduct          0x0565 
  bcdDevice            1.01
  iManufacturer           1 JMicron
  iProduct                2 JMS56x Series
  iSerial                 5 <removed>
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          121
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 USB Mass Storage
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                2mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              6 MSC Bulk-Only Transfer
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     98 
      iInterface             10 MSC BOT/UAS Transfer
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               0
        Command pipe (0x01)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               0
        MaxStreams             32
        Status pipe (0x02)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
        MaxStreams             32
        Data-in pipe (0x03)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
        MaxStreams             32
        Data-out pipe (0x04)
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength           22
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000f0e
      Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   1
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat          32 micro seconds
Device Status:     0x000d
  Self Powered
  U1 Enabled
  U2 Enabled
```

fdisk -l shows:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 testine, 63 settori/tracce, 121601 cilindri, totale 1953525168 settori
Unità = settori di 1 * 512 = 512 byte
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Identificativo disco: 0x0001cf00

Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            8040      498023      244992   fd  Autorilevamento raid di Linux
/dev/sdb2          498024      562271       32124   fd  Autorilevamento raid di Linux
/dev/sdb3          562272      809271      123500   fd  Autorilevamento raid di Linux
/dev/sdb4          809272   244187999   121689364   fd  Autorilevamento raid di Linux
```

hdparm -I shows:

```
ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       WDC WD10EARX-00N0YB0                    
        Serial Number:      <removed>
        Firmware Revision:  51.0AB51
        Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
        Supported: 8 7 6 5 
        Likely used: 8
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16383
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
        LBA    user addressable sectors:  268435455
        LBA48  user addressable sectors: 1953525168
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
        Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:      953869 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:     1000204 MBytes (1000 GB)
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
        LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
        Queue depth: 32
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, with device specific minimum
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 0
        DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
             Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
             Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
           *    SMART feature set
                Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    Write cache
           *    Look-ahead
           *    Host Protected Area feature set
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
           *    NOP cmd
           *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
                Power-Up In Standby feature set
           *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
                SET_MAX security extension
           *    48-bit Address feature set
           *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
           *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
           *    SMART error logging
           *    SMART self-test
           *    General Purpose Logging feature set
           *    64-bit World wide name
           *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
           *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
           *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
           *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
           *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
           *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
           *    Host-initiated interface power management
           *    Phy event counters
           *    NCQ priority information
                DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
           *    Software settings preservation
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
           *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
           *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
           *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
                unknown 206[7]
                unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
                unknown 206[13] (vendor specific)
Security: 
        Master password revision code = 65534
                supported
        not     enabled
        not     locked
        not     frozen
        not     expired: security count
                supported: enhanced erase
        186min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 186min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 50014ee2b14805a5
        NAA             : 5
        IEEE OUI        : 0014ee
        Unique ID       : 2b14805a5
Checksum: correct
```

If I cat `/sys/class/block/sdb/queue/physical_block_size` and `/sys/class/block/sdb/queue/logical_block_size` they both say 512.

So, with this docking station, I again see the drive as a "normal" 512-byte sector drive.

### Questions

1. why hdparm is saying something different than fdisk and `/sys/class/block/sdb/queue/physical_block_size` + `/sys/class/block/sdb/queue/logical_block_size` with both docking stations? hdparm is saying that the physical sector size is 4096, while the other say the physical sector size is 512 (like the logical one)
2. how is it possible that a very recent (bought in 2018) USB 3 docking station with a JMicron bridge supporting the newest UASP protocol is not seeing the drive as a 4k one, while a much older USB 2 SATA+PATA Bridge by JMicron too does? Is this an issue at all if I were starting to use this hard disk with these docking stations from scratch now?
3. as you can see, partitions on that drive are RAID members (RAID1); the partition table and RAID array was created when the disk was used with the JMicron SATA+PATA enclosure. Whenever I try to start the RAID arrays with this enclosure, I have no problems and I can read the contents on the disk; whenever I try to do the same with both docking stations, I get a "no superblock found error", so the array does not start and I cannot read the disk contents; this scares me a bit, because I fear I won't able to read the contents of that disk back if the enclosure one day fails

To overcome problem 3. I remember I could dd the partition of interest even when using the first docking station, by playing with block starts and sector size, so I could get an image on file which I could mount as a loopback device and get the original contents back, however I was wondering whether there's a simpler solution that doesn't force me to create an image of the whole disk.

Comment: This is very similar to this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403919/harddrive-with-4096-physical-sector-size-reported-as-512-behind-usb-bridge The answers here might help clear up the confusion ( or maybe make you more confused ;] )

Comment: USB enclosures aren't all created equal, sounds like you just found some duds

Comment: @LayneBernardo thanks Layne, I just pinged the author of that question to see if he discovered something more.

Comment: @MauroMolinari *I* didn't. (I'm not the question author, it's not my hardware.) I have a feeling there are some more questions like this on the U&L site though.

Comment: @Xen2050 you may be right, I'm just surprised that a recent JMicron bridge seems to behave wrong while an older JMicron one seems to behave right. And in any case, not being able to read back the contents on the disk is alarming.

Comment: As a reference: seems like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187748/recognizing-gpt-partition-table-created-with-different-logical-sector-size is suggesting a way to read contents back using losetup and specifying proper block size.

Comment: My understanding is that the logical block size is part of the abstraction of the physical drive which is used nowadays to allow more uniform and easier access to physical drives. Basically the kernel pretends that it's writing to an imaginary disk and that gets translated into real memory locations automagically. It seems like the kernel simply selects whatever block size it feels like using for the logical block size, and probably newer USB enclosures provide a similar type of abstraction and just report abstracted values, since it normally won't make any difference to the operating system.